# Reseting pandas row index to start at number other than 0?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, indexing

Currently I am trying to read in a .csv file and then use the to_html() to create a table with indexing on the side. All lines of code here:

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')  
df.to_html('example.html')
```

As expected I am currently getting:

```
   Year  Population      Annual Growth Rate 
0  1950  2557628654      1.458   
1  1951  2594919657      1.611  
2  1952  2636732631      1.717  
3  1953  2681994386      1.796   
4  1954  2730149884      1.899
```

However I want to start the indexing at 2 instead of 0. For example:

```
   Year  Population      Annual Growth Rate 
2  1950  2557628654      1.458   
3  1951  2594919657      1.611  
4  1952  2636732631      1.717  
5  1953  2681994386      1.796   
6  1954  2730149884      1.899
```

I know I could achieve this outcome by adding two dummy rows in the .csv file and then deleting them with df.ix[], but I do not want to do this.
Is there a way to change the indexing to start at something other than 0 without having to add or delete rows in the .csv file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it looks like a hack, but what if just change index series. For example:

```
df.index = df.index + 2
```

Comment: Not a hack!  It's the most straight forward, intuitive way to solve the OP's problem.  I'd go for the more aesthetically pleasing version of what you've done `df.index += 2`.  But thats just me.

Comment: df['row_num'] = df.reset_index().index+1